# Retrieving image stored in long datatype

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I have one web application, having one table in oracle10g having following structure:

```
Column Name       DataType
UserImage         long
```

My problem is that how should I display the IMAGE on my aspx page which is stored in long format?

If data type is BLOB or CLOB then it could be easier one, but it's stored in long.

I could not change the datatype since this is third party DB.

Please suggest me how could I achieve this. The solution could be either using Oracle or C#, I'm fine with both.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `LONG` is a character data type. So it cannot be used directly to store images. Either the image is encoded (e.g. in Base 64) or the datatype is `LONG RAW`. Can you post a sample of the contents of the *UserImage* column?

Comment: @Codo: in database it show's some junk character and that's why i m not able to copy pest it.

Comment: There is one sample code using which same thing is getting achieved at Database end, so can any one suggest me how could i achieve the same thing :                                                                     fo := utl_file.fopen(fpath,fname,fmode);
    Select image into x from asbasign ;
    Utl_file.put_line(fo,x);
    Utl_file.fclose(fo);

Comment: And how does this code relate to the table mentioned in your question? Is the table called *asbasign*? If so, why is the column called *image* and not *UserImage*?

Comment: Can you show some of these "junk" characters?

Comment: Junk Character is like as follows :                                                                      II*_h___,_______,_______¿_ P8$_
_¿BaP¿X_¿___¿!¿c¿-_¿FcQhdv=_¿0__¿pAn¿o¿¿R¿dbA/¿¿¿(¿¿¿¿¿¿¿gS¿¿¿_@¿¿_¿¿¿¿yG¿N¿¿¿;q¿_9$#¿ _¿¿¿¿;¿¿¿¿¿¿_¿¿¿¿¿{¿_>¿X-S¿¿Yz¿s¿__ %¿¿_¿¿_¿¿-¿¿v¿R¿¿¿_¿__¿¿qP¿¿X¿_db¿Y<¿W-¿¿fsY¿¿w=¿¿htZ=&¿M¿¿juZ¿f¿]¿¿lv[=¿¿m¿¿nw[¿¿¿}¿¿px\>'_¿¿¿ry\¿g7¿¿¿tz]>¿W¿¿¿v{]¿¿w¿¿¿x|^?'¿¿¿¿k  ¿_ P8$_
_¿BaP¿d6__¿DbQ8¿V-_¿FcQ¿¿v=_¿HdR9$¿M'¿JeR¿d¿]%_K¿P¿¿¿m_¿&¿¿__s<¿5¿_ ¿_¿D¿_gT¿}__L¿_¿¿ p>¿T¿¿¿_¿¿n\¿¿K_n__¿_W¿¿¿¿¿Uj¿(¿¿¿¿_¿¿_d¿¿*Q¿5¿_g¿^/¿[^___¿F¿¿x_¿_¿¿c¿/¿¿___¿a¿q¿¿___>e@_X¿¿D_¿_t¿Q¿p_¿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "chunk" characters you have posted seem to be a TIFF image. That gives an idea how the images are stored. In fact, the binary image data seems to be stored as character data. That's certainly completely unsupported and very fragile. I'd recommend converting it as soon as possible.

In the mean time, I can propose two ways of retrieving the data so I cannot guarantee that either one works.

But approaches are susceptible to characters sets: If two or more character sets are involved, your data will be converted and thereby destroyed. And both are susceptible to the maximum length of certain data types.

**Approach 1:**

Try to go via the RAW data type and retrieve it as a byte array. It's certainly limited to 32'000 characters, maybe even less.

```
SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(UserImage) FROM UNNAMED_TABLE WHERE ...
```

On the C# side, you should get an [OracleBinary](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleBinaryStructure.htm) or `byte[]` instance.

**Approach 2:**

Try to retrieve it as a string. Then convert the string into a byte array using the original encoding ([Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx). With enough luck, the original data can be restored.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it's throwing corrupt image i.e. a image with black background.

Comment: Then you need to carefully investigate whether you have received the complete image, whether it still has the same length, whether all bytes match the original ones etc. and possibly try a different approach. Which approach did you use anyway? BTW: It might even be that the images in the database are invalid because some conversion (like newline conversion) takes place on import. It currently still works because it is restored on export.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store an image in a 'long' datatype.

Instead - hold a static list of key-value pairs, each pair defines an index (say, from 1 to n) of an image
and the value holds the Image's file name.

For instance, the following pseudo code demonstrates a similar approach (should be implemented on the client/server side of your application, not in the DB

```
SWITCH (USERIMAGE)
    CASE 1:
         SETIMAGE("IMAGES/IMAGE_NUMBER_ONE.JPG");
         BREAK:
    CASE 2:
         SETIMAGE("IMAGES/IMAGE_NUMBER_TWO.JPG");
         BREAK:
```

and so on.

Another solution:

Assume your 1st table is called "Table1". create a new table in your database called my_images

```
Column name     Column type       Comments
UserImage       LONG              Foreign key to Table1.UserImage
ImageData       BLOB
```

And,

```
SELECT t1.ImageData FROM Table1 t1, my_images mi 
WHERE t1.UserImage == mi.UserImage;
```

Comment: @Codo in that case the first solution might fit